# Why does Grunt fail?

Tags: node.js, backbone.js, gruntjs

I'm getting a weird error after running `npm run-script grunt` in which it tell's me that `node_modules/.bin/grunt` fails.

I'm following a tutorial as im pretty new to Backbone (http://dailyjs.com/2012/11/29/backbone-tutorial-1/),

Here's my `package.json` file.

```
{
  "name": "btask"
, "version": "0.0.1"
, "private": true
, "dependencies": {
    "requirejs": "latest"
  , "connect": "2.7.0"
  }
, "devDependencies": {
    "mocha": "latest"
  , "chai": "latest"
  , "grunt": "latest"
  , "grunt-exec": "latest"
  }
, "scripts": {
    "grunt": "node_modules/.bin/grunt"
  }
}
```

And here's a full transcript of the error.

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'node',
1 verbose cli   '/Users/Keva161/.nvm/v0.8.18/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'run-script',
1 verbose cli   'grunt' ]
2 info using npm@1.2.4
3 info using node@v0.8.18
4 verbose read json /Users/Keva161/Documents/Web Dev/Webapps/Node/btask/package.json
5 verbose run-script [ 'pregrunt', 'grunt', 'postgrunt' ]
6 info pregrunt btask@0.0.1
7 info grunt btask@0.0.1
8 verbose unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
9 silly exec sh "-c" "node_modules/.bin/grunt"
10 silly sh,-c,node_modules/.bin/grunt,/Users/Keva161/Documents/Web Dev/Webapps/Node/btask spawning
11 info btask@0.0.1 Failed to exec grunt script
12 error btask@0.0.1 grunt: `node_modules/.bin/grunt`
12 error `sh "-c" "node_modules/.bin/grunt"` failed with 2
13 error Failed at the btask@0.0.1 grunt script.
13 error This is most likely a problem with the btask package,
13 error not with npm itself.
13 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
13 error     node_modules/.bin/grunt
13 error You can get their info via:
13 error     npm owner ls btask
13 error There is likely additional logging output above.
14 error System Darwin 12.2.1
15 error command "node" "/Users/Keva161/.nvm/v0.8.18/bin/npm" "run-script" "grunt"
16 error cwd /Users/Keva161/Documents/Web Dev/Webapps/Node/btask
17 error node -v v0.8.18
18 error npm -v 1.2.4
19 error code ELIFECYCLE
20 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: Are you on Windows? I had problem running grunt on Windows with that configuration...

Comment: no im on osx :/ ive tried installed grunt globally as well but same error

Comment: I don't think it's your case but I had to change the "scripts" section of package.json to this to work on Windows: `"grunt": "node_modules\\.bin\\grunt"`

Answer (score 23):

The tutorial that you are talking about uses grunt 0.3.
Grunt has updated since then and if you use    "grunt": "latest"    in your *package.json* file then you will get grunt 0.4 by default.

You can go through the [migration guide](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/wiki/Upgrading-from-0.3-to-0.4) to get things working.

In order to just get grunt working for the tutorial you can  do this -

- Install grunt-cli globally `npm install -g grunt-cli`
- Install grunt-init globally `npm install -g grunt-init`
- Install grunt locally (already installed if you followed the tutorial)
- Change    `"grunt": "node_modules\\.bin\\grunt"`    in *package.json* to    `"grunt": "grunt"`
- Rename *grunt.js* in root directory to *Gruntfile.js*
- Change    `grunt.registerTask('default', 'exec copy-require');`   in *Gruntfile.js* to    `grunt.registerTask('default', ['exec','copy-require']);`
- Run `npm run-script grunt` as usual in command-line. Things should work fine now.

You will get a build directory with r.js build.

If you still cannot get it working somehow with the above steps, you can change `grunt: "latest"` to `grunt : "0.3"` in your *package.json* file and run `npm install` in shell.

Comment: What is `grunt-init` and why is it necessary?

Comment: Grunt init is a scaffolding tool to auto generate your gruntfile and other project structure. (like yeoman). It is not at all necessary. More on it here http://gruntjs.com/project-scaffolding

Comment: where is global grunt root?

Comment: @Omar depends on where your global npm dependencies are installed. You can do `which grunt` in bash to find out

Answer (score 5):

[arunkjn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14695845/why-does-grunt-fail/#answer-14976496)'s answer will solve the problem. Though in accordance to the tutorial's intention, the author did not want to install grunt globally, which is also what I'm going for. Thanks to arunkjn, I figured that you could also:

- Install grunt-cli locally by `npm install grunt-cli`
- Rename grunt.js in root directory to Gruntfile.js
- Change `grunt.registerTask('default', 'exec copy-require');` in Gruntfile.js to `grunt.registerTask('default', ['exec','copy-require']);`

And do `npm run-script grunt` again and it should work.

Comment: **Grunt-cli** and **grunt-init** are meant to be installed globally.See point 2 [here](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/wiki/Upgrading-from-0.3-to-0.4) for details. In my answer above I have explicitly mentioned that you have to install grunt locally for it to work (and that is what the author intends to do).

Comment: Yeah, I know they are supposed to be globally. But the tutorial's author wanted everything to be local, just his style I supposed. Just a preference.

Comment: Generally speaking, I sympathize with the author as I like to use tools locally unless I know I'll be using it regularly. I think the local install keeps with the spirit of the tutorial - installing globally *then* locally kind of defeats the purpose. +1 for that and a simple answer.

Comment: Looks like you also need to change scripts section from `"scripts": {
    "grunt": "node_modules/.bin/grunt"
  }` to `"scripts": {
    "grunt": "node_modules/grunt-cli/bin"
  }`

Answer (score 2):

I've been using grunt and npm for a while now, and I've never used `run_script`. Maybe try this?

The `scripts` portion is usually for running on a remote server, (ie Heroku or Travis)

---

Remove the `scripts` block.

Then do

```
npm install -g grunt
```

May have to restart terminal after this.

```
cd myproject
npm install
grunt mytask
```